# Silence Evince's warnings in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, evince

I'm getting loads of Evince warnings when running it from the terminal. E.g.

```
(evince:4599): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/nivaca/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

(evince:4599): GVFS-WARNING **: can't init metadata tree /home/nivaca/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied

** (evince:4599): WARNING **: Error setting file metadata: can't open metadata tree

(evince:5001): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

I've searched everywhere how to fix this problems, but I haven't been able to do so.

Thus, what I want now is to *silence* these warnings, as they unable me to see what's really going on with my other processes in the terminal.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It looks like the user under which evince runs is not allowed to create files in the directory .local/.... Try changing permissions to 777 for /home/nivaca/.local/share/gvfs-metadata and see whether this changes anything, `chmod -R 777 directory...`

Comment: Thanks. That cleared up the first three warnings, but not the last one.

Comment: You mean Gtk-Critical?

Comment: Yes, that one...

Comment: You should read this question, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230238/starting-x-applications-from-the-terminal-and-the-warnings-that-follow and especially the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks. I added "export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1" to `\etc\environment` but the warnings keep popping up.

Comment: Not what I meant. The guy says the GTk-critical error is irelevant,and you can leave it at that.

Comment: Yes, I know is not critical. But in my workflow these messages are annoying: I'm LaTeXing and these warnings scroll up the messages that do matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't necessarily recommend this course of action, but you could put something like:

```bash
alias evince='evince 2>/dev/null'
```

which will remove all standard error from evince. I think that the minor annoyance of seeing them is better than the one time evince will actually fail and won't tell you why, but it is an option.

You could also do something fancier if you use bash, like:

```bash
alias evince='evince 2> >( grep -v "evince.*WARNING" >&2 )'
```

to filter out specific lines from standard error. This may be more safe, but I'm not necessarily endorsing it.